# ElasticSearch - total sum by all previous days

Tags: elasticsearch, sum, aggregation

I need to summarize all values by each day (exactly on this day) and total values by this day (sum of all values before this day, including this day values)

My code:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/tester/test/_search?pretty=true -d '
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "articles_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "month"
            },
               "aggs": {
                  "value": {
                     "sum": {
                        "field": "my.value"
                     }
                  }
            }
        }
    }
}
'
```

Output:

```
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {...},
  "hits" : {...},
  "aggregations" : {
    "articles_over_time" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key_as_string" : "2014-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1391212800000,
        "doc_count" : 36,
        "value" : {
          "value" : 84607.0
        }
      }, {
        "key_as_string" : "2014-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1393632000000,
        "doc_count" : 79,
        "value" : {
          "value" : 268928.0
        }
      }, 
      ... ]
    }
  }
}
```

This code gives me the first - summarize all values by each day (exactly on this day)
How can I gt the second one - total values by this day (sum of all values before this day, including this day values)

What do I need:

```
{
  "took" : 7,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {...},
  "hits" : {...},
  "aggregations" : {
    "articles_over_time" : {
      "buckets" : [ {
        "key_as_string" : "2014-02-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1391212800000,
        "doc_count" : 36,
        "value" : {
          "value" : 84607.0
        },
        "total" : {
          "value" : 84607.0
        },
      }, {
        "key_as_string" : "2014-03-01T00:00:00.000Z",
        "key" : 1393632000000,
        "doc_count" : 79,
        "value" : {
          "value" : 268928.0
        },
        "total" : {
          "value" : 353535.0 /// 84607.0 + 268928.0
        }
      }, 
      ... ]
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Is this because your second aggregation is nested in the "articles_over_time" section?

Does the following help? If you change from:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/tester/test/_search?pretty=true -d '
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "articles_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "month"
            },
            "aggs": {
                "value": {
                    "sum": {
                        "field": "my.value"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To:

```
curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/tester/test/_search?pretty=true -d '
{
    "size": 0,
    "aggs" : {
        "articles_over_time" : {
            "date_histogram" : {
                "field" : "date",
                "interval" : "month"
            }
        },
        "value": {
            "sum": {
                "field": "my.value"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not really, It just gives me total value for all over period, but not pr day.